# IntelliJ IDEA - SpringBoot project / cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to Java and Spring and I have troubles with writing a simple application.

Thing is, IntelliJ does not see my .jsp files that are in the project. The application works, but I am not getting help from IntelliJ.
I also can't use model I created in my HomeController class in my homepage.jsp with forms and modelAttribute, as it becomes red and does not support me writing the code.

.jsp files are in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/

I have application.properties file with:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Here are my files:

HomeController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(Model theModel){

        Credentials theCredentials = new Credentials();

        theModel.addAttribute("credentials", theCredentials);

        return "homepage";
    }
}
```

Credentials.java

```
public class Credentials {

private String username;
private String password;

public Credentials() {
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

homepage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

Welcome to the virtual deanery!!!
<br><br>

Please log in as Student or Teacher to continue:
<br><br>

<form:form modelAttribute="credentials"> 
<%--credentials are not found--%>

<%--somecode--%>

</form:form>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Which IntelliJ edition? The community or the ultimate one. For that to work you need the latter, it won't work on the community edition.

Comment: I am using the ultimate 2017.2 edition.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the exact same problem..

Comment: Unfortunately not - it seems that it's some kind of a bug...
I mean it worked, but still IntelliJ was acting as if it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have something wrong with your web-inf directory mark.
Right click on webapp -> mark directory as -> sources root

Comment: thanks - I already tried this and it didn't work. Also tried to mark src folder as sources root, without success.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add spring Facet with springs configurations [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU6V9.png)